# wireless connection not connecting windows 8

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration, adsl, adsl2+

I have a broadband connection and internet in all other devices on my WiFi is working.

On the laptop, which is running Windows 8, I am not able to connect using the WiFi.

You can see the screenshot I am connected via a LAN wire but WiFi is unable to connect.

[image]

What should I do in here?

The router being used is aBeetel 450TC3.

Here you can see while connecting with WiFi on Laptop this gives problem:

[image]

output of ipconfig/all

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]

C:\ >ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : HP
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : domain.name

Wireless LAN adapter Lenovo Easyplus Hotspot
:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

   Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::548b:
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.107(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 04 March 2016 14:10:45
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 07 March 2016 14:38:23
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : fe80::bac1:a2ff:fe1e:144c%3
                                       192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

You can see following screenshot for modem settings:

Comment: Your router settings screenshot is missing. Please [edit] and add the link.

Comment: What are the DHCP settings on your router, your laptop, and the other devices? If you don't use DHCP, are the IP settings of your laptop correct?

Comment: Please [edit] and add the output of `ipconfig /all` (run in a `cmd` shell).

Comment: I need a reputation of at least 10 to post router screenshots I tried adding them but could not post here.

Comment: I have not made any DHCP settings to any devices all devices automatically pick up the IP from ADSL router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem  might occur frequently with many users hence I am posting the solution. What happens is that the routers broadcast waves on some frequency and various channels. Some times the Wireless card which comes default embedded in our laptops is not able to scan the frequency of router or connect to the channel on which router is broadcasting. Usually this setting is done by router in auto mode. 
Unless some geek changes the channel on which router should broadcast which receiver at your laptop should be able to pick. Usually Auto mode on routers work perfectly. But in some cases like mine I found  use of  an external USB wireless adaptor like this one http://www.amazon.in/USB-wifi-Adaptar-dongle-wireless/dp/B00W97H75I?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=46dcded8-0bea-4080-8701-f8ab33d4406c

solves this problem. In my case I have tried at various places I still have the laptops wifi which also scans the network but is not able to connect. But using external USB wifi it solves the problem.